# Date calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have the following list with calculated date columns

[image]

I have used the following formula for both the Last Visit and Next visit

```
=TEXT(Next,"dd mmm, yyyy")

=TEXT(Last,"dd mmm, yyyy")
```

The top three items do not have anything added in the date field but the calculated column shows 30 Dec 1899.

Can I add something to formula to not show a date in no date has been added to the item?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(Next="","",TEXT(Next,"dd mmm, yyyy"))
```

Note: A Blank date is a FALSE value, so this Formula can shortened to:

```
=IF(Next,TEXT(Next,"dd mmm, yyyy"),"")
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, what formula would I use to show how many days has past since the last Visit column based on todays date?

Comment: =TODAY()-Last. You can use Excel (and search engine) to get formulas: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF([Next]="","",TEXT([Next],"dd mmm, yyyy"))
```

[Find Below Link for more example](http://sharepoint.rackspace.com/calculated-columns-tutorial)

Comment: The code is an exact copy of @thomius code?